# Slot argument is (sometimes) invalid

Tags: c++, qt, qeventloop

In one of like 10-20 signal invocations i have an invalid argument in the slot. The problem boils down to the following

```
class Sender : public QEnabledSharedFromThis<Sender>
{
public:
    void emitSignal() 
    {
        emit someSignal(sharedFromThis())
    }

signals:
    someSignal(const QSharedPointer<Sender>&);

    int m_i;
};

qRegisterMetaType<QSharedPointer<Sender>>();

Sender sender;

class Receiver
{
    Receiver()
    {
        connect(&sender, &Sender::emitSignal, this, [this](const QSharedPointer<Sender>& sender) {
            // Crash here.
            // 'sender' argument seems invalid (dangling reference)
            qDebug() << sender->m_i;
        })  
    }
};
```

When this happens I can see in the crash dump in  `QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2` (for example) that:

```
event->nargs == 2 // ok
event->type[0] == 0 // ok
event->type[1] == some reasonable value like 1105
event->sender is alive and seems correctly initialized
```

But `event->args` seems to be invalid.

```
event->args[0] != 0
(Sender*)(args[1]) is full of  'can't read memory'
```

Platform is Win64, qt version is 5.6.1, compiler is vs2015. Release.
Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a complete program that demonstrates the problem? This one has syntax errors. Also, what platform/compiler and version of Qt are you on?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. This is a huge production application. I can't reproduce this with artificial tests.

Comment: Platform is Win64 and it seems that problem is more likely to reproduce when a target machine has limited cores (1 on virtual machine).

Comment: You certainly can reproduce it with artificial tests. I've recently faced a similar issue and traced it down to a compiler bug in a rather popular and up-to-date compiler. You need to set yourself up to catch the bug first: be sure you can quickly rebuild the solution and automatically determine whether the problem occurs or not. Then start paring down the code. In most cases you will end up with something under a 100 lines long even if you start with a huge code base. I started with 100k lines and ended up with a stand alone repro case 5 lines long.

Comment: Here's how I did it: Started a new branch in git. My problem was a crash so it'd already exited with error code 255 if it crashed, and 0 otherwise. Then I started removing all the code I didn't have to invoke to have it crash. About 90% of the application went away. Then there were background control tasks that turned out to be immaterial as well - another 5% gone. Then I started axing the UI away. Eventually included all `ui_foo.h` files into `main.cpp` and started removing swaths of code from those. Then it was 10 lines of Qt-using code.

Comment: Then I included all needed Qt code so that I could stop using the Qt framework as a whole. I could disable threads, got rid of QString and lots of other things, eventually ending up with a very bare application shell that used no plugin code. After paring that down, the repro case was a stand-alone single C++ file that clearly demonstrated a compiler bug in 5 lines. Even though initially it was hopeless.

Comment: To give you some encouragement, a gal I know, responsible for a code generator, once hit a codegen bug when compiling Inkscape, a 400kLOC project back then. The resulting test case was 150 lines long. Took her a week to get to the bottom of it, but it was worth it :)

Comment: If your issue is only happening in release, you might want to check if it also only happens with MSVC2015 Update 3. Microsoft introduced a new optimizer in that release, which is also known to create issues in Qt Declarative/QML. S.a. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55238